# "Давать слабину" или "давать слабины"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно употреблять данный фразеологизм:

> давать слабину

или же

> давать слабины

?

Answer (score 4):

**1) Винительный падеж: дать/ давать слабину**

Но стоило защите гостей дать слабину... С каких пор твои на зависть эластичные нервы дают слабину? С ними нельзя давать слабину.

**2) Родительный падеж при отрицании (основной):** **не давать слабины**

Ты не давай душе слабины и скоро встанешь. Но Петров слабины не давал и дрался жестоко, используя в бою все средства, вплоть до зубов.

**3) Винительный падеж при отрицании в частных случаях**

Рыба мечется, сопротивляясь, а мне важно не дать леске слабину.

Answer (score 1):

Давать (что?) слабину. Это винительный падеж. Порылся в словарях, нашёл только такой вариант. [См.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/42525/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_) здесь.

Comment: Интересно, что с отрицательной формой глагола в разговорной речи может использоваться и родительный падеж...  Похоже, сродни "не давать покоя" (вместо "не давать покой").